# Task Manager Memory Usage Does Not Agree with "top" command Memory Usage

Tags: lubuntu, ram

I just installed lubuntu 12.04 and have been monitoring memory usage with the "top" command and the task manager GUI.

I'm currently seeing 448 MB of physical RAM used with "top".

However, task manager is telling me that 202 MB is in use.

I only have 500 MB total and am seeing decent performance, so I'm wondering if "top" has an issue.

Can anyone explain the difference between "top" and task manager?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include links to images of both so we can see all the numbers (someone here will add them so they are shown as images).   From memory: what you see is disc caching. Start here and follow the link in the 1st answer: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/183940-memory-usage-top-vs-system-monitor-solved.html

Answer (score 0):

top includes cache/buffered to the used memory.  While other tools do not.  top reports I'm using almost 3.7 GB!!  But it also show about 2.6 as cache so I'm realy only using about 1.1 GB.  (which is what htop reports)  I recommend htop over top.  It's just as lightweight and useful as top, but with extra features.